# f2py does not properly import, despite successfully compiling

Tags: python, python-3.x, fortran, f2py

I am successfully compiling my Fortran subroutine with f2py. However, a folder is created as well as a pyd file.

If I do not put the created pyd file in the generated folder I get this error

`ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.`

If I put the generated .pyd file in the generated folder, my python script will run, and the import seems to work. However, if I run `print(energy_f2py.__doc__)` `None` is the output, and when I try to use the subroutine I get an error `AttributeError: module 'energy_f2py' has no attribute 'potential_3'`

`potential_3` is the name of the `subroutine` inside `energy_f2py.f90`

I have also tried making `energy_f2py.f90` a module containing the subroutine, with no difference in results.

This is the pyd file that is generated `energy_f2py.cp36-win_amd64.pyd`. I am using the commandline in Pycharm (windows 10 64 bit) to compile the Fortran file using

1. `f2py -c -m energy_f2py energy_f2py.f90`
2. `python -m numpy.f2py -c -m energy_f2py energy_f2py.f90`

The same thing happens.

It seems weird to me that both the pyd file is created as well as a folder, see the below image
[image]

I am stuck at this point... it seems like it is 95% of the way to working...

Lastly, [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8564771/compile-fortran-module-with-f2py) had a solution saying to name the Python and Fortran modules different names. I have tried this, and it did not make a difference either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I found which worked was to partition my hardrive and install Linux. I chose to use Lubuntu, but you could use anything.

Everything works as it should on Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Anther option to is to make it a static build, with the `-static` flag. This builds everything needed into a single file:

```
python -m numpy.f2py -c -m energy_f2py energy_f2py.f90 -static
```

You should then be able to use that `.pyd` file no matter what folder you've placed it in.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using windows, I think adding  *--compiler=mingw32*  may help. The defualt compiler is msvc on windows.

Answer (score 1):

It occurs to me that the resulting `.pyd` module is looking for the DLL library in the same directory it itself resides in. Therefore, try moving the DLL from `.libs` directory to `energy_f2py` - it worked for me on Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same issue and found the solution.
Python when resolving dependencies for imported extension modules search for some paths. We can add the folder ".libs" to it via

```py
# __init__.py
import os
os.add_dll_directory("/path/to/.libs")
```

So you don't need to move the DLLs in ".libs" to other places. Note to check for the existence of ".libs" before adding it to dll directory.

Answer (score 0):

ry to add the specific folder where to compile and generate the intermediate files and then include that folder (-I option)

An example would be:

f2py -c -m energy_f2py energy_f2py.f90 --compiler=mingw32 --fcompiler=gnu95 --build-dir C:\000_Scripts\temp_energy -IC:\000_Scripts\temp_energy\Release

The Release folder is automatically create by f2py. You should only create temp_energy folder.

This work for ok for me with the same issue.