# Fortran module complied using f2py but not able to import the module in a python script: module could not be found error

Tags: python, fortran, python-import

I have compiled a few Fortran codes in Python using f2py (**windows 10**). The compilation was successful, but when I try to import the module, it gives the error:

```
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing exsnow: The specified module could not be found.
```

Here 'exsnow' is the name of the module I am trying to import.

I have tried a few things till now by browsing through this site:

(1) copying '*.dll' file to the same directory as '*.pyd' file as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60898233/f2py-does-not-properly-import-despite-successfully-compiling).

(2) compiling the fortran code with '-static' flag as mentioned in [this same post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60898233/f2py-does-not-properly-import-despite-successfully-compiling).

The first solution simply did not work as it gives the same dll error. But I am not sure if I have done it properly.

The second solution gives error during compilation:

```
Don't know how to compile -static
```

Is there anything else I could to make it work?

The command that I used to compile the code is as follows:

```
 f2py -c -m exsnow exsnow19.f PACK19.f
```

Directory structure of the complied module is as follows:

```
snow19
   | exsnow/.libs/*.dll
   | '*.pyd'
```

The command that I use to import the module is:

```
import snow19.exsnow as snow17
```

Comment: The "specified module" may not necessarily be the compiled "exsnow" itself but may be a DLL needed directly or indirectly by "exsnow". A tool like https://github.com/lucasg/Dependencies may help.

Comment: I am sorry. I do not understand what you mean by 'specified module may not be the complied exsnow'.

Comment: The error mentions a "specified module" that couldn't be found.

Comment: I see. Let me see how can I use that tool to identify the problem.